# Where to put new fridge?

Tags: kitchens, refrigerator, layout

Just bought our first house and we're trying to make two main improvements to the kitchen:

1. There's no microwave and not really enough counter space for one (But I'll save this for a subsequent post)
2. The fridge sucks.  I've been without an ice maker and cold water dispenser for over four years now and I really miss it.

There's a bit of a problem with measurements and timing.  We move in in a month and unfortunately it will be difficult to get in to make more measurements than the ones I have above.  We'd like to take advantage of some pretty good appliance sales right now and get their delivery delayed until we've moved in.  We should also be able to cancel delivery if it turns out we measure things and it won't work; we'll of course be double checking with that before ordering.

I'll make this post just about the fridge: No fridge exists that would fit in the current fridge niche while still being an improvement.  We can't do any major renovation right now, so the most natural choice is to put a fridge in the corner that currently contains that colorful and adorable Hoosier cabinet.  I assume the previous owners are taking it with them.  A typical fridge we're looking at has a width of 36" and a depth of 32".  The wall behind the cabinet is 48" wide, and it's probably 24" from the window to the wall ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°).  So there's plenty of clearance there width-wise.  The problem is it'll extend 8" past the window; more after including the clearance behind the fridge needed for the water line.

My main question is: How bad do you think that overhang will look?  On the one hand, we should have a solid 6" clearance between the fridge and the window.  It's also 24" or so to the edge of the trim; so that 8" overhand will be including the casing and sash, so it might not actually overhang the glass too much.  On the other hand, these windows have the option to open inward; we'd be sacrificing that ability for the left window, but I'm not sure we'd ever actually use it.

(NOTE: A couple things we don't need to worry about; there's an outlet behind the Hoosier cabinet, and the kitchen is right over the utility/laundry room so getting a cold water line up there should be easy)

[image: Fridge in corner]
[image: Hoosier cabinet in corner]
[image: Stove in corner]

Comment: "*My main question is: How bad do you think that overhang will look?*"  Atrocious and you will be flogged for violating the laws of refrigerator aesthetics.  **If it is temporary then what difference does it make if it sticks out a little?**

Comment: when picking your location, remember that you'll need a water supply line for the ice maker and cold water dispenser. What is the size of the existing refrig opening?

Comment: @AlaskaMan I'm gonna assume that's sarcasm :) Well, temporary as opposed to messing with cabinetry; it might be a few years before we find a better solution, or it might never happen.  So you're not thinking it'll be a bad setup?

Comment: can you put the new fridge where coffee maker is and the cupboard with the coffee where the current  fridge is, mount a shelf above the coffee maker and put microwave in there.

Comment: @JACK It shouldn't be too hard, as the area right under the kitchen is an unfinished utility/laundry room.  I should have a short path from there to the wall above.  :)  The existing opening is 32".  There are very few options that will fit in that gap, next to none of which have a water dispenser.

Comment: @AndreiMihailevski That won't be an option right now.  We don't want to mess with the cabinetry for a while.  After other projects in the house are done, we might take on something bigger like that.

Comment: This is entirely a matter of opinion, and therefore [off topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). We don't do layout design here. Sorry.

Comment: The cabinet "around" the refrig could be easily moved to the corner giving you enough room for a larger refrig... Just a thought.

Comment: If you do this, what are your plans for the big empty space where the existing fridge is?

Comment: Jimmy Fix-It, still figuring that out.  Probably we'll clean the area up nicely, make sure paint, molding, etc., matches, and put in a 28"-30" butcher block cart. So we can pull it out for cooking prep as needed, but it will also be functional counter space.  We might also mount the microwave at the top of it, if we decide against an OTR microwave.

Answer (score 1):

Cabinets are usually easy to remove: they're held to the wall and to adjacent cabinet units with only a handful of screws.

If the loss of some storage space won't put you in a bind then remove the cabinet unit that sits above the refrigerator. That'll allow you to bring in a taller unit. Or, if more width is your thing, remove the cabinet unit to the left side of the fridge. Or do both.

If you decide it was all a terrible mistake it'll be a relatively straightforward thing to violate refrigerator aesthetics by moving it where it partially blocks the window. The cabinets, if you stored them somewhere, could then be re-hung in their original places without too much effort.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't put it in that corner, you are going to bang the door into the widow sill all the time and dent it, it will look terrible in short order.

Look harder for one that will fit the existing fridge space, they exist. What you want to look for is called a "counter depth" refrigerator, which sets the standard for the depth you need. There ARE a few choices out there for counter depth with a water dispenser and ice in the door, I know because I have the exact same problem and found a few. I bought the one from GE, Profile series counter depth, door dispenser, 33" width. I had found some that were 32" wide too, I just liked the GE better.

Not an endorsement, just an example.

https://www.geappliances.com/appliance/GE-ENERGY-STAR-17-5-Cu-Ft-Counter-Depth-French-Door-Refrigerator-GYE18JMLES